# To use AND and OR both together in google sheet query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Is there any way I can use both operator i.e. AND and OR in the Google Sheets Query.
For e.g.

```
"Select * where Col1 contains 'Yes' or Col2 contains 'Yes' and Col3 contains 'Please'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
"Select * where (Col1 contains 'Yes' or Col2 contains 'Yes') and Col3 contains 'Please'"
```

add parenthesis